Specifying node's x and y coordinates wrt. drawn line
I want to draw a line, and create a node with a specified position wrt. that line. I would like the node to be to the left of the midpoint.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (5,5) \node[below=2.5,left=2.7] {my node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However writing it like this, tikz only reads off the last command (so it ignores the vertical displacement, and only shifts the node horizontally wrt. the line's endpoint). Perhaps it's really obvious, but is there a neat fix for this?
edit: As pointed by campa below, changing \node to node solves the problem.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Works fine for me once I correct \node to node.

Of course, that makes sense. I've corrected it to a minimal working example. @campa, the suggested correction works, thank you!
